Past Perfect Continuous with the conjunction "before" instead of "when"
Which one is more common?
I had been playing basketball for two hours when you called me.
I had been playing basketball for two hours before you called me.
I have done some research on the Internet and it seems "before" has more results with "past perfect simple."
Is "when" more common with the past perfect continuous tense?

Yes, when is more "natural" in the cited context. In practice they'll both mean exactly the same thing in virtually every case, but the reason we don't favour the before version is probably because it tends to imply that the earlier action (me playing basketball) was a necessary "precursor" to the following event (you calling me), which might be thus seen as a result, outcome. As in "I was knocking on the door for ten minutes before he opened it and let me in".

...but if you wanted to imply that he should have called earlier, and you were only playing basketball to pass the time while you waited for him to call, by all means use before

Also note that you can't really use Simple Past with when in such contexts - it wouldn't normally make much sense to say "I played basketball for two hours when you called me" (the only possible meaning there should be conveyed by ...after you called me, not before).

I think we don't prefer "before" because "before" implies that something was completed, which is a little weird for "past perfect continuous tense", which refers to actions that continued to the moment when another action took place. In other words, in this case, the playing of basketball began before the call but continued to the moment the call took place.

Why are you asking, if you're just gonna disagree with what a native speaker tells you? "before" doesn't imply that something was completed - that would be done by using Simple Past: I played basketball for two hours before you called me.
